# Why is my array coming out as shape: (6, 1, 2) when it is made of two (6, ) arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to import data from an excel and create an array `pos` with 6 rows and two columns. Later, when I go to index the array `pos[0][1]`, I get an error: `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1.`

I looked at the shape of my array and it returns `(6, 1, 2)`. I was expecting to get `(6, 2)`. The individual shapes of the arrays which make up `pos` are `(6, )` and `(6, )` which I don't really understand, why not `(6, 1)`? Don't quite understand the difference between the two.

```
irmadata   = pd.read_excel("DangerZone.xlsx")
irma_lats  = irmadata["Average Latitude"].tolist()
irma_longs = irmadata["Average Longitude"].tolist()

shipdata   = pd.read_excel("ShipPositions.xlsx")
ship_lats  = shipdata["Latitude"].to_numpy()  ## these are the (6, ) arrays
ship_longs = shipdata["Longitude"].to_numpy()
pos = np.array([[ship_lats], [ship_longs]], dtype = "d").T

extent = [-10, -90, 0, 50]
ax = plot.axes(projection = crs.PlateCarree())
ax.stock_img()
ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE)
ax.coastlines(resolution = "50m")
ax.set_title("Base Map")
ax.set_extent(extent)

ax.plot(irma_longs, irma_lats)
for i in range(len(ship_lats)):
    lat = pos[i][0]
    lon = pos[i][1]   ## This is where my error occurs
    ax.plot(lon, lat, 'o', label = "Ship " + str(i+1))

plot.show()
```

Obviously, I could just index `pos[0][0][1]` however, I'd like to know why I'm getting this issue. I'm coming from MATLAB so I suppose a lot of my issues will stem from differences in how numpy and MATLAB work, and hence any tips would also be appreciated!

Comment: I believe the problem arises from `ship_lats` and `ship_longs`. Please post the shape of these two in the question or the comments

Comment: They are both `(6, )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, I didn't realise I could just use single square brackets for combining my two column arrays. So, changing `pos = np.array([ship_lats], [ship_longs]], dtype = "d").T` to `pos = np.array([ship_lats, ship_longs], dtype = "d").T` worked.